# JaxWS RI /JaxB - Shared Object between Handler and WebMethod

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

Does it exist a way to share a object between handler and webmethod?

The reason why I'm asking it is that I want to log the raw request
to the database, process the request on StoredProcedure (By ID KEY) and log on the same record the raw response.

To get this I want share the ID KEY between handler and webmethod and demand the log of request and response raw to handler.

tnx.

**Update**

You must use Setter Method on you WS Implementation.

If you want set parameter in message context you must set scope application for parameter.

The Default Scope is Handler not visible in WS Implementation

SoapHandler

```
 public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {

 smc.put("ID_MESSAGGIO",message.getId());
 smc.setScope("ID_MESSAGGIO", MessageContext.Scope.APPLICATION);

}
```

WS Implementation

```
   WebServiceContext context;

    @Resource
    public void setContext(WebServiceContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public CreateAndStartRequestByValueResponse   createAndStartRequestByValue(CreateAndStartRequestByValueRequest parameters) throws CreateAndStartRequestByValueException {

        MessageContext messageContext = context.getMessageContext();

        Long theValue = (Long) messageContext.get("ID_MESSAGGIO");
        return controller.startCreateAndStartRequestByValue(parameters);
    }
```

tnx at all.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-WS provides the [`MessageContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/rpc/handler/MessageContext.html) for that purpose.

In your handler:

```
 @Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
  //This property checks whether the handler is being invoked for a service response
  boolean request= ((Boolean) context.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_INBOUND_PROPERTY)).booleanValue(); 

  if (request) { //check to make sure the handler is operating on an inbound message
   context.setProperty("propertyName","propertyValue");   
  }
  return true;
}
```

In your service implementation:

```
 @Resource
 WebServiceContext wsCtxt;

 @WebMethod
 public YourServiceResponse operation(YourServiceRequest req){

     MessageContext msgCtxt = wsCtxt.getMessageContext();
     String theValue = msgCtxt.getProperty("propertyName").toString(); //obligatory null check

 }
```

Comment: Does the property has scope for request and response?

Comment: While I'm not absolutely certain, since the `MessageContext` is preserved for the same request and response, the property is good for the same scope @AntoninoBarila

Comment: There is no method `setProperty`on `javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext`